# Wrong required validation for datepicker input field

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-validate

I am taking input of date of birth in `dd/mm/yyyy` format and using the datepicker plugin

```
<input type="text" id="birth_date" name="birth_date" value="" class="form-control date">
```

And jQuery for date class is

```
$('.date').datepicker({
    todayBtn: "linked",
    keyboardNavigation: false,
    forceParse: false,
    calendarWeeks: true,
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
});
```

When I validate input field using jQuery Validate it gives me error "Please enter a valid date." for only `dd/mm/yyyy` format, instead it is working fine for `mm/dd/yyyy` format

```
$("#frm").validate({
    rules: {
        first_name: { required: true },
        date_of_birth: { required: true }
    },
    messages: {
        first_name: { required: 'Please enter first name' },
        date_of_birth: { required: 'Please select the date of birth' }
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.insertAfter(element);
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

Why I am getting this error as I am only validating for `required` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Why I am getting this error as I am only validating for required field?"*

The jQuery Validate plugin can pick up rules in several ways, including, but not limited to...

- Declared within the `rules` object of the `.validate()` method.
- HTML5 inline attributes, such as `required="required"`.
- Class names, such as `class="required"`.

When you use `class="date"` on the `input` field, you are invoking the `date` rule within the jQuery Validate plugin.  Remove the `date` class from the `input`.  If you depend on the `date` class for a visual style, then you must change the name of this class to something else.

Comment: Thanks @Sparky.. I have changed date class to input_date, and it solved my issue