# Validating HTML5 separated form with jQuery.validate()

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have the following JS and HTML:

```js
$('#html5submit').click(function() {
  $('#html5form').validate({
    rules : { html5required: { required: true} },
    submitHandler: function(e) {
      $.post({
        //My AJAX here works just fine
      });
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<form id = "html5form"></form>

<input form = "html5form" type = "text" name = "html5required" required maxlength = "200">
<input form = "html5form" id = "html5submit" type = "submit">
```

Is the above code already correct?

My idea is to **disallow** the form to submit, and yet I will be running some updates/inserts on my database by calling said AJAX. **If I erase the** `rules` **part of the JS**, I can run the AJAX just fine. However, **doing the above** did not validate my input field, i.e. AJAX still ran even though the field is empty!!!

1. If I place `required` on my HTML `input`, is it necessary to repeat `required` rule on my JS? What's the best practice of placing `required` in situation like this (when the form is separated and I'm using jQuery form validation)?
2. Is what I'm doing correct on the above? I assume that as I will only trigger form validation only when I have clicked the submit button, I placed the `$('html5submit').click(function(){});` section to know when to trigger validation.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?  Your question is very unclear.  What does HTML5 have to do with anything?  Also, you should not have `.validate()` enclosed within a `click` handler function.  `.validate()` is only used to **initialize** the form.

Comment: @Sparky I see, that makes sense. I'm merely trying to see whether my input field is empty or not before I call my AJAX function. However, my code above does not work (it does not validate the input field).

Comment: @Sparky I mentioned HTML5 form because I think that it might somehow interfere with the jQuery validator because typical forms have their inputs inside said forms. As mentioned in an answer below, separated inputs did interfere with jQuery validator, confirming my suspicion. Nevertheless, I have asked once more to reconfirm because I'd really like to use the type of form above (for tab implementations).

Comment: @Sparky Please do guide me to ask clear questions as I also want to be clear so that others can help me.

Comment: For basic usage, read the wiki page for this plugin:    https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info

Comment: @Sparky Wow! That link is totally good. Thank you. Is there some sort of repository for links (concise guides) like the one you gave? It will definitely save me in many situations.

Comment: It's just the "Learn More" link of the [tag:jquery-validate] tag.

Comment: For this plugin to work, **YOU MUST** place your `input` elements within the `<form>` container.  It makes absolutely no sense why you wouldn't already be doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated within comments, you have a few issues...

1. For this plugin to work, all `input` elements MUST be within a `<form>` container.  There is no workaround.
2. The `.validate()` method is used for initializing the plugin on your form, and therefore should be called once on page load rather than on every `click` event.  Remove & replace the `click` event handler with a document ready event handler.
3. When you've already declared `required` within the `rules` object of `.validate()`, then you can remove the corresponding HTML5 attribute.  For consistency, you should also remove the `maxlength` HTML5 attribute and declare this in the `.validate()` method.  When using this plugin, all HTML5 validation is automatically disabled.  If you prefer to declare all rules via HTML5 attributes, then you should remove them from `.validate()` and the plugin will still pick them up as valid rules.  This is only my suggested best practice as having [different rules in different locations leads to confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54751708/594235) when troubleshooting.
4. There was a stray semicolon `;` at the end of your `submitHandler` function causing a syntax error.

**Working Code**:

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#html5form').validate({
        rules: {
            html5required: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 200
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(e) {
            $.post({
                //My AJAX here works just fine
            });
        }
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="html5form">
    <input form="html5form" type="text" name="html5required">
    <input form="html5form" id="html5submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

**Working DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/s0qgdjm4/2](https://jsfiddle.net/s0qgdjm4/2/)**

**More Info:**

For basic usage of this plugin along with best practices, see the [SO Wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info) for the [jquery-validate](/questions/tagged/jquery-validate) tag.

[Official Documentation here](https://jqueryvalidation.org).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure as what you are trying to achieve. But you can add a function in the jQuery validate if the form is not correct, called invalidHandler, see here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#html5form').validate({
 rules : { html5required: { required: true} 
 },
 invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
 // Make ajax call here
 $.ajax();
 },
 submitHandler: function(e) {
   $.post({
     //My AJAX here works just fine
   });
  };
 });
}
```

In this case, the onclick of the submit button can be removed, as the form will automatically be validated if the form is submitted. If the input has the required tag, the rules can be deleted. Just play around with it and use the [documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/).

Comment: No no, I'm not trying to make an `invalidHandler`, but thank you for the extra info. I simply want my `input` to be given an invalid event that says 'This field cannot be empty' (like when you want to register a Gmail account and you leave your First Name). **That is my problem here**. Even when my input is empty, I can still **submit the form and the AJAX call of submitHandler runs**.

Comment: Also, why do I need `$(document.ready(function(){});` to wrap my validation? isn't it okay to not wrap it in that?

Comment: @WealthyPlayer, read all of my comments on this page and read [the Wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info).   The `.validate()` method is used for INITIALIZATION of the plugin on your form after the page is loaded.  The document ready handler ensures the HTML is fully loaded before the plugin is initialized.   You do not need a `click` handler because the click event is already captured automatically by the plugin.

Comment: The best answer would be a combination of the two first answers on this page.  This one missed the inputs outside of the form container and the other answer missed the removal of the `click` handler.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reaction, but if you want to place the error on a custom place, use the errorplacement method. I recently made a generic jQuery validate snippet, see here: https://jsfiddle.net/ec6azns4/2/. In this example, the class for the error and the text are given to the input as an attribute.

Comment: You missed the whole point.  The OP's code is **broken** simply because they didn't put the `input` elements INSIDE of the `<form>` container.

Comment: @Sparky Thank you. Your comments have been very helpful. Posting it as an answer would certainly be accepted :-D

Answer (score 1):

Adding the required attribute to form elements will result in the browser 'validating' the input. But whenever a user goes into dev tools of the browser they can easily remove this. By using validator it is already safer, but not impossible to bypass this security measure. 
The only true way to validate is validating in php, because the user can't change the code there.

As for getting the validator to work,
fixing these couple things will make it work:

- You **need** to wrap the input elements in the form element, this is just how jquery validator works.
- Remove the semicolon in the json object that is used by .validate()

Doing this will give you the following result, which will work and prevent the submitting of the form when left empty.

```js
$('#html5submit').click(function() {
  $('#html5form').validate({
      rules : { 
      html5required: { 
        required: true
      } 
    },
    submitHandler: function(e) {
      $.post({
        //My AJAX here works just fine
      });
    } // There was a semicolon here!
  });
});
```

```html
<form id = "html5form">
  <input form="html5form" type="text" name="html5required" maxlength="200">
  <input form="html5form" id="html5submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have already validated my input in PHP. I merely want to show some notification if their inputs were invalid. One more thing, is it really impossible to use jQuery validator with the above type of form (inputs that are not enclosed in a form)?

Comment: If it is really impossible to validate the form without enclosing the inputs in the form? What other method can I use to validate my AJAX form then?

Comment: @WealthyPlayer No, it is required to surround the input tags with a form tag. This is required by jquery validator

Comment: @WealthyPlayer To validate a dynamically created form you have to put the .validate() **after** the form is created.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is a dynamically created form?

Comment: @WealthyPlayer That is your AJAX form

Comment: REMOVE the `click` handler.  It's completely unnecessary and shows a total lack of understanding about how to use this plugin.  `.validate()` is how you INITIALIZE the form... then the `click` is captured *automatically*.

Comment: A dynamically created form is a form that is ***created*** by ajax.  The OP's form is not dynamically created - it is loaded with the HTML and *submitted* by ajax.

Comment: @Sparky You are totally right, completely missed that. However it is not the cause of the problem that is being asked about, the cause of the form still submitting is because you need to wrap the input elements. Do you agree?

Comment: @RickJelier It seems that I do need to wrap the input elements. Is there a way to validate them without using jQuery.validate() plugin then?

Comment: @WealthyPlayer you can achieve this by manually checking the input element's value when onclick is being ran of the submit button

Comment: The OP **MUST** wrap all `input` elements within a `<form>` container in order for this plugin to work.  There is no way around that.

Comment: And read my comment about the `click` handler... it's pointless and it could possibly delay validation in certain usage cases.

Comment: The best answer would be a combination of the two first answers on this page.  This one missed the removal of the `click` handler and the other answer missed the inputs being outside of the form container.